# R function that produces "invalid" for text/character variable

Tags: r, function, compare

I am trying to create a function in R, which outputs "pass" if an integer is greater than 100, "fail" if less than 100, or "neutral" if equal to 100. The code should say "invalid" for a character variable/text.

This is the code I have so far:

```
compare <- function(x) {

 if (x>100) {
  result = "pass"
 }

 else if (x<100) {
 result = "fail"
 }

 else if (x==100) {
 result = "neutral"
 }

 else if (is.character(x) == TRUE) {
 result = "invalid"
 }

 print(result)

 }

compare(10)
compare(100)
compare(120)
compare("text")
```

I am expecting compare(10) to produce "fail", compare(100) to produce "neutral", compare(120) to produce "pass", and compare ("text") to produce "invalid". All the integers work, however, compare("text") continually produces "pass" instead of "invalid". Compare(as.character("text")) also only produces "pass".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create conditional statements, you need `==` not `=`.

```
compare <- function(x) {
  if (!is.numeric(x)) {
    result = "invalid"
  } else  if (x>100) {
    result = "pass"
  } else if (x<100) {
    result = "fail"
  } else if (x==100) {
    result = "neutral"
  } 

  print(result)
}
```

This function worked for me. The following is the output test.

```
> compare(10)
[1] "fail"
> compare(100)
[1] "neutral"
> compare(120)
[1] "pass"
> compare("hello")
[1] "invalid"
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried to adapt your code for the question above, it didn't work (I also tried using as.integer). I reposted the full question above.

Comment: `compare <- function(x) {
  
  if (!is.numeric(x)) {
    result = "invalid"
  } else  if (x>100) {
    result = "pass"
  } else if (x<100) {
    result = "fail"
  } else if (x==100) {
    result = "neutral"
  } 
  
  print(result)
}`

To be honest, I am not 100% sure it seems writing 
`if (!is.numeric(x)) {
    result = "invalid"
  }`
in the first was needed.